# SwiftUI update Button label after audio is finished to play with timer updating

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, avaudioplayer

I'm building a player with SwiftUI. It's working, I play and pause the audio, changing the slide value, the audio is changing the audio position.

I've a problem at the end of the audio, the button doesn't update its label with play icon, but it's remaining in the pause icon.

**during the play:**

[image]

**at the end I would like this:**

[image]

```
struct BubbleAudio: View {

let text: String
var unzipPath: URL

@State private var playValue: TimeInterval = 0.0
@State private var isPlaying: Bool = false

@State private var playerDuration: TimeInterval = 120

@State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(playValue.stringFromTimeInterval())
        .font(.system(size: 11, weight: .light))
        .offset(y: +10)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            if self.isPlaying {
                if let currentTime = Sounds.audioPlayer?.currentTime {
                    self.playValue = currentTime
                }
            }
            else {
                self.isPlaying = false
                self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            }
        }
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                if self.isPlaying {
                    self.isPlaying.toggle()
                    Sounds.audioPlayer?.pause()
                }
                else {
                    self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
                    if Sounds.playWAAudio(text: self.text, unzipPath: self.unzipPath) {                           
                        self.isPlaying.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }, label: {
                  if isPlaying {
                    Image(systemName: "pause")
                    .font(Font.system(.title).bold())
                  }
                  else {
                    Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                    .font(Font.system(.title).bold())
                  }
            })
            .frame(width: 35)
            .fixedSize()
            Slider(value: $playValue, in: TimeInterval(0.0)...playerDuration, onEditingChanged: { _ in
                self.changeSliderValue()
            })
            .frame(width: 200, height: 10, alignment: Alignment.center)
            Text(playerDuration.stringFromTimeInterval())
            .font(.system(size: 11, weight: .light))
        }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        self.playerDuration = Sounds.getDuration(text: self.text, unzipPath: self.unzipPath)
        print(self.playerDuration)
    }
}

func changeSliderValue() {
    Sounds.audioPlayer?.currentTime = playValue
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, i'm finding your code very helpful. The only aspect i'm struggling with is how you are updating the slider in realtime as the audio is playing? When I pause the audio the slider moves to the correct place but whilst it's playing the slider doesn't move. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JoshuaBrowne you have to use and update $playValue  as "@State" var, you could post a new question, tag me on the comment and I'll help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rather here, in `.onReceive(timer) {`

```
if let currentTime = Sounds.audioPlayer?.currentTime {
    self.playValue = currentTime
    // reset playValue, so reset isPlaying if needed
    if currentTime == TimeInterval(0.0) { // only explicitly
       self.isPlaying = false 
    }
}
```